# After applying the color to the button element, the color property of an element returns null

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

I am trying to get the color property of the button element using Javascript inside Selenium, before and after clicking the button.

**HTML code:**

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    
    #container
    {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    
    #content
    {
        margin:4px, 4px; 
        padding:4px; 
        width: 500px; 
        height:500px; 
        text-align:justify; 
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    button
    {
        color: orange;
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content">Click the button to slide right!</div>
    </div>
    
    <button id="slide" type="button" onclick="dem_func();">Slide right</button>
    
    <script>
    
    function dem_func()
    {
        document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 50;
    <!-- Changing the text color of button element-->
        document.getElementById('slide').style.color='red';
        return document.getElementById('slide').style.color;
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Working of the HTML code:**
Orange color is applied to the button text through CSS. On clicking the button, the Javascript `dem_func()` gets invoked which changes the text color of button to red and it should return the text color of the button element.

**Selenium code:**

```js
    //Before clicking the button
    String color7 = (String)js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('slide').style.color");
    System.out.println("Color of the text of button element: " + color7);

    //After clicking the button
    String color8 = (String)js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('slide').click();");
    System.out.println("Color of the text of button element: " + color8);
    String color9 = (String)js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('slide').style.color");
    System.out.println("Color of the text of button element: " + color9);
```

`color9` returns `red` as expected.

`color7` returns `null`, but the expected value is `orange`

`color8` returns `null`, but the expected value is `red`

Any reason why both `color7` and `color8` returns `null` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would get colors as expected if we had developed code like:

```
<button id="slide" type="button" onclick="dem_func();" style="color:orange;">Slide right</button>
```

The below line is trying to get the color name from the 'inline' color element instead of "<style//>" css block:

```
document.getElementById('slide').style.color
```

Since there is no inline styling, we are getting blank value.

To solve cases with style sheets, we can use getComputedStyle. Something like:

```
String color7 = (String)js.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('slide')).getPropertyValue('color')");
System.out.println("Color of the text of button element: " + color7);
//Result would be -> Color of the text of button element: rgb(255, 165, 0)
```

We can write our code or use readily available jars to convert RGB to actual color names.

`Color8` resulting `null` is expected.

Comment: Can you please explain why the color8 null is expected ? Because I am returning the value in Javascript onclick() function upon clicking the button..

Comment: @SandeshSawant `document.getElementById('slide').click()` is a void function it has no return value that's the  reason it gives you null